# Toggle Accordion plus/minus icon

Tags: jquery, toggle, accordion

I have a working accordion and the only issue I have right now is getting the current icon from the open panel to toggle when you select another accordion header.

The icons currently toggle when you click on the accordion header that is already selected.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

**HTML**

```
<div class="description-container">

<div class="accordion">
   <h2 class="section-header">Heading 1</h2>
   <div class="panel">
      <p class="text-light">
      • Made from all-natural, sustainable, and non-splintering rock-hard maple wood that makes sore gums happy!
      • Non-toxic, untreated, & sealed with all-natural and eco-friendly beeswax
      • Naturally anti-bacterial
      • BPA & phthalate free (thank goodness!)
      • Intricately designed with love and sanded by hand
      • Made from scratch entirely in NYC, from start to finish
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
   <h2 class="section-header">Heading 2</h2>
   <div class="panel">
      <p class="text-light">
      • Gift ready in unique recyclable packaging, featuring all of LexyPexy's exclusive (and cute!) designs
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".section-header").addClass("closed");

$('.section-header').click(function() {
$(this).parent(".accordion").find('.panel').slideToggle();
$(this).parent(".accordion").siblings().find('.panel').slideUp();
$(this).toggleClass("closed active");
return false;
});
```

Here is a working Demo - [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ryman/6wj8ckvp/)

Comment: this for sure will help: https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/3amzhp6z/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Close all the other `$('.section-header')` and remove the class `active`

2) Toggle the one which is being clicked

Here's a demo:

```js
$(".section-header").addClass("closed");

$('.section-header').click(function() {
  let $this = $(this);
  let $others = $(".section-header").not($this);
  
  $others.addClass("closed").removeClass('active');;
  $others.siblings().slideUp();

  $this.toggleClass("closed active");
  $this.siblings().slideToggle();

  return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.accordion:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.panel {
  display: none;
}

.section-header.active::after {
  content: "\2212";
  color: #000;
  display: block;
}

.section-header.closed::after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #000;
}

.section-header::after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description-container">

  <div class="accordion">
    <h2 class="section-header">Heading 1</h2>
    <div class="panel">
      <p class="text-light">
        • Made from all-natural, sustainable, and non-splintering rock-hard maple wood that makes sore gums happy! • Non-toxic, untreated, & sealed with all-natural and eco-friendly beeswax • Naturally anti-bacterial • BPA & phthalate free (thank goodness!) •
        Intricately designed with love and sanded by hand • Made from scratch entirely in NYC, from start to finish
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <h2 class="section-header">Heading 2</h2>
    <div class="panel">
      <p class="text-light">
        • Gift ready in unique recyclable packaging, featuring all of LexyPexy's exclusive (and cute!) designs
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Very nice! I like how you used the "let" limiting the variable to that block element. And I see how you handled toggling the effect with the "not" selector. Very recursive and clean. I like it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing more!

```css
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header-active:after{
 float:right;
 content:"-";
}

.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header-collapsed:after{
 float:right;
 content:"+";
}
```